# Where are Wolverine's underpants?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, when [Wolverine was getting infused with Adamantium in the Weapon X facility](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1628l488dI), the following still from the film reveals that he was strapped-on at the floor of the chamber, wearing black underpants.

[image]

(*Please correct me if you think I am getting this wrong, but I think those appear to underpants and not straps. Notice the curvature of the straps around the crotch area, as opposed to the straightness of the chest strap. Also, the needles were clearly periodically arranged on the sides, so there was no reason for Wolverine to not be wearing anything in the pelvic region*.)

Yet, a few seconds later, when Wolverine breaks free from the chamber, he emerges wearing his birthday suit (at 1:36 or 1:37 in the linked video). In fact, after breaking free, there is also [a shot where he streaks across the field of an old couple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EovTfanoNcA).

So, where did Wolverine lose those underpants? Or were those merely some straps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NO, there were no underpants. They were straps.

Checking from other angles, *it's definitely a strap.*

[image]

[image]

If you zoom in you can even see clasps of strap in second snapshot.

[**Snapped from here in 480p.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sqio1tiPGk)

Comment: Thanks. An image of the clasps would really be clinching evidence for this matter. If you can see them, can you please post that zoomed shot as evidence?

Comment: This does not answer the question, but just confirms the supposition of the OP.

Comment: @Joachim: OP asked if it was underpants or straps. I think I have answered it pretty clearly that those were straps.

Comment: @Joachim I agree Rahul and also think the question isn't just trivia. If these were underpants, it means hole in the plot, that might be explained, e.g. some lost scene explaining what happened to them.

Comment: @Rahul The OP asked where the underpants were lost (see the title), and whether or not they were straps was only part of the query.

Comment: @Joachim: Okay. I'll add some part to my answer.